# Installing Virtual PC in Fedora

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows-xp, virtual, fedora

I currently use a Windows 7 Home Basic. I need to run a certain application, which is, as of now not supported, i.e. compatible with/by W7HB. I tried downloading Virtual PC with XP mode, which does not support W7HB. Hence, I have installed Fedora as a dual boot, as there exists a separate edition of the application for Linux. As I am new to Linux CLI, I would like to install a version of XP in Fedora, i.e. via Virtual XP, assuming it supports. However, I am not able to find any suitable article for the same. Any suggestions...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use VirtualBox.

There are 2 options:

run W7HB as the 'host' and install VirtualBox.Then install a guest operating system such as Fedora or WXP inside virtualbox.

OR

run Fedora as the host and install VirtualBox. Then install a guest operating system such as W7HB or WXP.

Be warned that if you install Windows in any form in a virtual machine you will need a Windows installation key. This may require a phone call to Windows support.

There are other solutions - VMWare, KVM, ... but IMHO VirtualBox is the simplest